# Why would describe layouts endpoint return ENTITY_IS_DELETED error

Tags: rest-api, describesobject, page-layout

I am working on a project that uses OAuth against SF via REST on behalf of users from a variety of organizations. For one of our users, I am able to call SObject describe on their Account object and get back what seem like normal results. "Account" is queryable, editable, etc. And there are recent accounts which I can query and get the records. The SObject results also return the URLs to use for querying layouts. When I query these I get the ENTITY_IS_DELETED error (consistently).

Under what situation would this occur? We are using v29 (winter 2014).
thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post the resource you're querying (e.g. /services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Account/describe/)? Also, verify that the Authorization header isn't missing... the more information we have, the better. I'm not able to recreate this even with a limited user account (I even turned off Account: Read access, and they can still describe it!)

Comment: sorry for the delay. `curl -L https://na11.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Account/describe/layouts -H 'X-PrettyPrint: 1' -H "Authorization: OAuth <access_token_here>"`         
The result (and sorry I am not sure how to add a line break here for readability): [ {
"errorCode" : "ENTITY_IS_DELETED",
"message" : "entity is deleted"
} ]